# How to align outside text in a go.Bar?

Tags: python, plotly

I would like to know if is it possible to align the outside text on the right ?

[image]

To have something like that :

[image]

Comment: See this:[https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/#bar-charts-with-text](https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/#bar-charts-with-text)

Comment: Are there only textfont, textposition and textangle to manage that ? If this is the case, there is no possibilites to align them vertically

Comment: Wouldn't a horizontal bar graph of the fourth sample in the link in your comment give you the graph you want? What do you mean by vertically aligned?

Comment: I did not understand what the desired output you are looking for. Could you explain that on the image itself? What alignment are you intending to do?

Comment: I added the picture of what im trying to do, I would like all prices to be aligned to the right while outside the bar chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- have simulated some data to be similar to implied in your image
- this can be achieved by placing **text** on an *invisible* bar that will always have same aggregate total
- also noted that you have negative values that also show as positive on **xaxis**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "bar": list("ABCDEF"),
        "val": [i * 10 ** 3 for i in [55, 50, 40, 36, -5, -10][::-1]],
    }
)

# main figure with the bars
df = df.assign(absval=lambda d: d["val"].abs(), color=lambda d: d["val"].lt(0))
fig = px.bar(df, y="bar", x="absval", color="color")
fig.update_layout(xaxis_visible=False, showlegend=False)

# figure with the text
df["pad"] = (df["val"].max() + df["val"].max() / 8) - df["absval"]
text_fig = px.bar(df, y="bar", x="pad", text="val", color_discrete_sequence=["rgba(0,0,0,0)"])
text_fig.update_traces(texttemplate="%{text:,}")

fig.add_traces(text_fig.data)
```

[image]